# How difficult is it to remove a domain & IP from UCEPROTECTL3 blacklist?

Tags: email, blacklist

How difficult is it to remove a domain & IP from the UCEPROTECTL3 blacklist? I was investigating and noticed it's not a particular issue with my domain/ip but with the whole Web Hosting provider. What do you recommend to do?

I'm trying to post a question because I have a doubt/issue. I expect it gets answered by other experts

Comment: While I'm not sure this question fits Stack Overflow, it may be better at https://serverfault.com/ . However, to answer your question, UCEPROTECT seems to lack nuance and it blocks whole sets of IPs based on the actions of a few IPs within those sets, so some of your neighbouring IPs may be sending some spam so you're caught as collateral damage. Your solution will be to discuss with your Server Hosting Provider but they probably won't do anything as they make money off unqualified people buying hosting and causing these kinda problems.

Comment: They also can't/won't usually move sites to whole new IP address blocks. On the plus side,  due to the way it works apparently many email protection systems don't rate UCEPROTECT very highly because of it's "collateral damage" issues described here.